# How to design a script that will use many user inputs from another page using AJAX & PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

In a nutshell.... what i want to do is a install script for my website... but i want everything to be done in 1 page which will connect to another php file that will have all the server side processing code. In order to do that i use JQuery, Ajax & PHP...

Now my question lies in what are the best practices in order to do that. How do I make my server side PHP script to take multiple user inputs that will happen throughout a lengthy installation processes?

I was thinking on using switch statements that will trigger classes & functions and like that being able to access multiple processes (Classes and functions) that will be stored in the same file?... or people normally use other things?? never done this before and couldnt find a straight forward tutorial for it on how is best to design it.

I was thinking on maybe being able to access classes through AJAX in php but that doesn't seem to be possible.... can i trigger functions from AJAX in php?

I really appreciate the help in how normally this is approached

thx

Comment: What's wrong with posting the data using a HTML form? Then save the form variables as sessions?

Answer (score 0):

It would be too lengthy to define the whole process in SO in detail. But the basic idea is:

- User fills in form clicks NEXT button.
- You get all the form values (in JavaScript), post it to a PHP page using AJAX
- The PHP page gives you back a flag (SUCCESS/ERROR) [In the background, if it is success, PHP has persisted the data into a database]
- If JavaScript receives ERROR, you show user the error message and ask him to correct the form
- If java script receives SUCCESS, you call the next PHP script, which generates the next form and sends it to your JavaScript
- JavaScript populates this form content within a DIV in your page, effectively wiping out the current form and showing the new form in its place.

..and the whole process restarts from the first step once again for the new form..

Comment: Mainly is like.... Insert db details.. if anything fails... return error... if it is ok... proceed to create a db login details file... if problems with creating file... return error... if not proceed to create tables... if problem with that return error... if not procedd... etc etc... so basically its a constant communication with various functions... that if it comes back will have to return to the same place and call the same function to try to fix it... so guessing that i would have to create a switch function with a parameter that would call each phase (function)

Comment: so that i returns to the same step that i was before returning the error... or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Yeah, that is one way of doing it. If you are traversing the path the reverse way (i.e from step 3 the user clicks BACK button and goes back to step2), then you will need to check the DB, fetch the saves values of step 2 and populate in the step2 form, so that the user can edit it. 

So the idea is that while rendering each form, check if `yes`already a database entry for its values, if yes, fetch and populate the form and when user clicks next `UPDATE` into db. If `no`, show blank form where user can enter data and when user clicks next `INSERT` into db.